# How to access AWS SAM Mapping in swagger.yaml / openapi.yaml files

Tags: swagger, openapi, aws-serverless, aws-sam

I have declared a mapping named `StageMap` in my `sam.yaml` file:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31

Parameters:
  ProjectName:
    Type: String
  SubProjectName:
    Type: String
  Stage:
    Type: String
    AllowedValues:
      - dev
      - test
      - preprod
      - prod
...

Mappings:
  StageMap:
    dev:
      AuthorizerArn: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:auth-bk-main-dev-AuthorizerFunction-1RR2YJ5STBUB6/invocations
    test:
      AuthorizerArn: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:auth-bk-main-test-AuthorizerFunction-UQ1EQ2SP5W6G/invocations
    preprod:
      AuthorizerArn: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:auth-bk-main-preprod-AuthorizerFunction-UQ1W6EQ2SP5G/invocations
    prod:
      AuthorizerArn: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:auth-bk-main-prod-AuthorizerFunction-5STBUB61RR2YJ/invocations
```

I would like to use this mapping in my `swagger.yaml` I have tried the following:

```yaml
...
x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
  type: request
  authorizerUri:
    Fn::FindInMap:
      - 'StageMap'
      - Ref: 'Stage'
      - 'AuthorizerArn
```

I also tried [this solution](https://www.arnaudcharlier.be/blog/index.php?2019/01/11/59-using-mapping-into-cloudformatino-and-openapi-yaml) but I got an error `Every Mappings attribute must be a String or a List`.

Can you please let me know how to access one of the values in the mapping in the `swagger.yaml`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following in the [AWS SAM docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/mappings-section-structure.html):

> You cannot include parameters, pseudo parameters, or intrinsic functions in the Mappings section.

So I changed:

```yaml
AuthorizerArn: !Sub arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:auth-bk-main-dev-AuthorizerFunction-1RR2YJ5STBUB6/invocations
```

For:

```yaml
AuthorizerFunctionName: auth-bk-main-dev-AuthorizerFunction-1RR2YJ5STBUB6
```

And in the `swagger.yaml` I used the following:

```yaml
x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer:
        type: request
        authorizerUri:
          Fn::Sub:
            - arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/arn:aws:lambda:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:function:${AuthorizerFunctionName}/invocations
            - AuthorizerFunctionName:
                Fn::FindInMap:
                  - 'StageMap'
                  - Ref: 'Stage'
                  - 'AuthorizerFunctionName'
```